# Specific Alternative for Invoke-Expression when calling starship

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I am using `starship` to configure my prompt in `Powershell`.

The `starship` documentation supplies this code that is now added to Profile, so the propt is available on startup of `PS`:

```
Invoke-Expression (&starship init powershell)
```

Now I am playing with module `PSScriptAnalyzer` and it is Warning me not to use `Invoke-Expression`.

On further reading I see that Invoke-Expression is a potential security risk.

Is it a security risk in the context of how I'm using it?
If so then is there a specific alternative I can use in my Profile?

I've tried using `& starship init powershell` in my Profile without success, as this is written to the host on start-up:

> Invoke-Expression (& '/usr/local/bin/starship' init powershell
> --print-full-init | Out-String)

Comment: What is the output of the commands `uname -a` and `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a security risk in the context of how I'm using it?

Whether it is a security risk ultimately doesn't depend on whether or not you use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression), but only on whether you trust the code being executed - and it's fair to assume that you *do* trust the code that comes with [Starship](https://github.com/starship/starship).

While `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) is [generally to be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375), the case at hand *is* a legitimate use:

`& starship init powershell` *outputs PowerShell source code*, which - in order to take effect for prompt customization - must be dot-sourced, i.e. executed directly in the caller's scope (rather than in a child scope).

Passing code to `Invoke-Expression` *implicitly* dot-sources it, and is the simplest way to do so for code that isn't already saved in a *file* (`*.ps1`); in the latter case, you would use `.` , the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-).

The equivalent - but more verbose - approach that avoids `Invoke-Expression` is to combine [`[scriptblock]::Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create) with the `.`  operator (which, like `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), can also act on [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)):

```
# Parse the PowerShell source code output by `starship init powershell`
# into a script block...
$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create((& starship init powershell))
# ... and execute it dot-sourced
. $scriptBlock
```

---

As an aside, re why `Invoke-Expression` is *also* used *in the code output by `starship init powershell`*, as shown in your question, effectively resulting in a *nested* `Invoke-Expression` invocation:

This indirection is used in order to produce *single-line* output from `starship init`, given that passing *multiple* strings to `Invoke-Expression` *as an argument* would break the call; e.g.:

```
# !! FAILS, because only a *single* string (though possibly multiline) 
# !! may be passed.
Invoke-Expression ('1+2', '3+4')

# OK, via the pipeline: -> 3, 7
'1+2', '3+4' | Invoke-Expression

# OK, as a *single* *multiline* string
Invoke-Expression "1+2`n3+4"
```

The reason that multiline output from an *external program* turns into *multiple strings* is that PowerShell relays the *lines* in a program's output as a *stream of separate strings*, which become a string *array* when captured or passed as an argument; e.g.:

```
# Passes each output line (with trailing newline remove)
# separately through the pipeline:
# -> '[one]', '[two]'
sh -c 'echo one; echo two' | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }
```

<sup>On *Windows*, use `cmd /c 'echo one& echo two'` as input.</sup>

As shown above, passing multiple strings *via the pipeline* to `Invoke-Expression` does work, so that the **initialization code could be simplified** as follows:

```
starship init powershell --print-full-init | Invoke-Expression
```

Even when using an *argument* the initialization could be simplified, by directly incorporating the [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) call:

```
Invoke-Expression (starship init powershell --print-full-init | Out-String)
```

If maximizing performance is the goal (though I doubt it will be noticeable in practice), use the [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) operator to join the output lines with newlines (`` "`n" ``):

```
Invoke-Expression ((starship init powershell --print-full-init) -join "`n")
```